# Multiple return types with interface{} and type assertions (in Go)

Tags: interface, go

I'm wondering what the correct syntax is for calling functions with multiple return values, one (or more) of which is of type `interface{}`.

A function which returns `interface{}` can be called like this:

```
foobar, ok := myfunc().(string)
if ok { fmt.Println(foobar) }
```

but the following code fails with the error `multiple-value foobar() in single-value context`:

```
func foobar()(interface{}, string) {
    return "foo", "bar"
}


func main() {
    a, b, ok := foobar().(string)
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf(a + " " + b + "\n") // This line fails
    }
}
```

So, what is the correct calling convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foobar() (interface{}, string) {
    return "foo", "bar"
}

func main() {
    a, b := foobar()
    if a, ok := a.(string); ok {
        fmt.Printf(a + " " + b + "\n")
    }
}
```

You can only apply a [type assertion](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Type_assertions) to a single expression.

Answer (score 1):

After the generic support for golang.

```
package main

func foobar[T int | string]() T {
    var a T
    return a
}


func main() {
    foobar[int]()
    foobar[string]()
}
```